# Añadir loading spinner en Toastr

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy usando la libreria [Toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) para generar notificaciones cuando se realizan acciones.

tengo este código que me añade una editorial y me genera un toastr mientras se esta añadiendo con ajax:

```
// JavaScript Document

toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": true,
  "progressBar": true,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};

$("#addeditorials").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    toastr.success("Please, wait a moment...", "Creating new Editorial");
    var btn = $(this);
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
    if (!form.valid()) {
        return;
    }
    btn.addClass('kt-spinner kt-spinner--right kt-spinner--sm kt-spinner--light').attr('disabled', true);
    form.ajaxSubmit({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './index.php?action=editorial-add',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function(response, status, xhr, $form) {
          setTimeout(function() {
              location.reload();
          }, 2000);
            
        }
    });
});
```

Estoy intentando cambiar el icono del toastr por un spinner en vez de un check pero no encuentro forma de realizarlo.

¿Alguien sabría modificar el icono del toastr?

Comment: ¿Alguien sabría modificar el icono del toastr o crear incluso un nuevo toastr que sea .loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modificando en CSS el icono del Toastr info y el color de fondo he conseguido poder usar el info para mostrar un icono de carga mientras se realiza una acción con AJAX.

El icono lo añadí en base64.

```
#toast-container > .toast-info {
  background-size:24px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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") !important; }
```